# Installing a single pole smart motion light switch in a three wire configuration

Tags: electrical, smart-switch, conversion

I have two three-way switches controlling two lights in my laundry room at either entrance. I want to remove one altogether and replace the other with a Kasa motion sensing dimmer switch which is single pole and requires a neutral.

On existing switch 1:

- incoming 14/2 black and white.
  When testing the wires, white is      energized, black is not
- outgoing 14/3 red,black and white
  White incoming and outgoing are
  connected
- black from 14/2 is connected to common
- Red and black from 14/3 are travellers

On existing Switch 2

- incoming 14/3
  Red and black are travellers,
  white to common

I have tried every possible combination of things i can think of without success. I want to eliminate switch 2 altogether and just use switch 1 as a single pole. I cannot determine if the power is incoming to switch 1 from the lights or if switch 1 is where the power comes in. Since the white is energized on the incoming 14/2, I’m thinking it is but there is no access to that in the ceiling…

Help!

Comment: I'm not a code expert, but I'm 99.999% certain that you need to have a light switch at any and every entry to a room, even if there are "smarts" that will turn the lights on from the other switch. Plus, unless you remove the cable from the wall, you'll still have to have a blank plate at the removed switch, so you may as well just leave the switch there.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove one altogether and replace the other with a Kasa motion sensing dimmer switch which is single pole and requires a neutral.

You don't have a neutral at either switch.  You'll need to leave the existing switches, or find an appropriate product for the purpose, or rewire the light and switch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the following:

Power comes in to one of the light fixture boxes.

- Hot (black) connects to white going down to Switch 1.
- Neutral (white) connects to neutral on the fixture.
- A separate black/white cable extends switched hot (black) and neutral (white) to the second light fixture.
- The cable going down to switch 1 has white (hot, noted above) and black (switched hot)

Switch 1 box has:

- Black (switched hot - common from switch 1)/white (hot) from the fixture box.
- /3 cable between switches has black and red (travelers) and white (continues the switched hot from the fixture box to switch 2).

Switch 2 box has:

- Black and red travelers and white hot (from fixture box -> switch 1 box -> switch 2 common).

The end result is that switch 1 does not have neutral. There are really only two ways to fix this:

- New /3 cable from fixture box to switch 1 to also carry neutral. This could be trivial or hard depending on whether the wall/ceiling are open or not.
- Smart switch that does *not* require neutral. Normally this means it needs ground, but you can't make that decision on your own. There are very strict limits of how much current a switch can get when connected to ground instead of neutral - i.e., it has to be officially UL or ETL listed with "no neutral" as an option.

Comment: Ok so I opted for the “ no neutral” choice…. So now the big question - which switch box makes the most sense to attach to? Either is ideally positioned for motion sensing….